# Excel workbook trying to save to network directory when it shouldn't when running macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a macro to work where it saves a file a certain format and reopens it to avoid compatibility issues, however, when the macro runs it tries to save to a network directory that is no way specified in the code.

```
Dim wkbook As String

wkbook = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wkbook, FileFormat:=52
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Workbooks.Open Filename:=wkbook
```

Comment: I couldn't see where you specify the directory / path.  Right now the workbook will save to it's current directory?  Or, what are you intended to do?

Comment: You specify the workbook name to save as, but you don't specify a path, so it will save to the current directory

Comment: I am intending for it to save in its current directory e.g. "My Documents" however excel is trying to save to a network directory and hangs when it runs the macro.  If I cancel the save, the macro continues on without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChDir to set the directory.

```
ChDir("C:\mydirectory")
```